# Tensor product $E\otimes_{A} F$ of modules $E,F$ where $F$ has a basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, direct-sum

> Let $A$ be a ring, $E$ a right $A$-module and $F$ a left $A$-module.
>   Let $(b_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ be  a basis of $F$. Then every element of
>   $E\otimes_AF$ can be written uniquely in the form $\sum_{\mu\in
>  M}(x_\mu\otimes b_\mu)$ where $x\in E^{(M)}$.

Attempt:

The mapping $v:\bigoplus_{\mu\in M}Ab_\mu\rightarrow F,\,y\mapsto\sum_{\mu\in M} y_\mu$ is an $A$-module isomorphism. Furthermore, there exits a $\mathbf{Z}$-linear bijection
$$g:E\otimes_A\bigoplus_{\mu\in M}Ab_\mu\rightarrow\bigoplus_{\mu\in M}(E\otimes_AAb_\mu)$$
such that $g(x\otimes(y_\mu)_{\mu\in M})=(x\otimes y_\mu)_{\mu\in m}$ for $x\in E$ and $y\in\bigoplus_{\mu\in M}Ab_\mu$. Thus the mapping
$$[1_E\otimes v]\circ g^{-1}:\bigoplus_{\mu\in M}(E\otimes_AAb_\mu)\rightarrow E\otimes_A F$$
is a $\mathbf{Z}$-isomorphism. At this point, I don't how to deduce the required property: that every element $z\in E\otimes_A F$ can be uniquely written in the form $\sum_{\mu\in
 M}(x_\mu\otimes b_\mu)$ where $x\in E^{(M)}$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a pure tensor $x\otimes y$, with $x\in E$ and $y\in F$. By assumption,
$$
y=\sum_{\mu\in M}a_\mu b_\mu
$$
and therefore
$$
x\otimes y=\sum_{\mu\in M}(xa_\mu)\otimes b_\mu
$$
Now passing to generic elements of $E\otimes_A F$ is easy.

What about uniqueness? Consider the isomorphism $g\colon A^{(M)}\to F$, $g((a_\mu)_\mu)=\sum_\mu a_\mu b_\mu$
Then define
$$
\tau\colon E\times F\to E^{(M)},\qquad \tau(x,g((a_\mu)_\mu))=(xa_\mu)_\mu
$$
Prove it is balanced, so it induces a group homomorphism $E\otimes_A F\to E^{(M)}$ and show that an obvious map is its inverse.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is the inverse given by the rule $x\mapsto\sum_{\mu\in M}x_\mu\otimes b_\mu$, for $x\in E^{(M)}$?

Comment: @alf262 Yes, that’s it.

Comment: @alf262 The result is actually a special case of $E\otimes_A(\bigoplus_\mu F_\mu)\cong \bigoplus_{\mu}(E\otimes_A F_\mu)$.